# I ran a UserBenchmark test and the graphics are at about 1.21%. What are some ways to fix this for cheap or free?

Tags: framerate, nvidia-geforce-experience, graphics-card

My benchmark: https://www.userbenchmark.com/UserRun/44519424
[image: trash graphics]

```
Specifications: 
NVidia GTX 940M
Core i7-6500U (which is 2.5 GHz)
HP envy notebook (basically a laptop)
```

I have about 40-60 fps for low settings in MC (stated in my previous question) and 20-60 for low settings in Roblox (specifically Phantom Forces).

Plus, all of my hardware seems to be performing under expectations.

Let me know if you need more information.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that your system is in some way overloaded. Your heat sink might be clogged, your fans too slow, your harddrive or ram almost full, and/or there are too many background processes running.

Open it, clean it carefully (help is on YouTube), then re-run the benchmark after weeding out startup processes, running programs, and make sure your C drive isn't full.

Comment: The "high background CPU" warning says the issue is probably software, not hardware.

Comment: Thanks! I just needed help on where my system might be bottlenecking.

Comment: Do you have any YouTube videos for my laptop?

Comment: Look in your task manager first. Always make sure to close ALL programs before running the benchmark, including background programs such as Google Drive. Also make sure that your energy mode is set to "Performance".

Comment: Do you think there might be malware making the system slow? I have also restarted my computer and run the benchmark with similar results.

Comment: Use the task manager to see which processes take up any CPU time. Is there anything unusual or unneeded there?